# How to highlight given string in given place?

Tags: sed, awk, perl, ksh

How can we modify this:

```
<a href="http://foo.bar1">asfdlksafbar1qsasadf</a><br>
<a href="http://foo.bar2">svasfbar2saldkfj</a><br>
<a href="http://foo.bar3">safdfrhbar3saljfd</a><br>
<a href="http://foo.bar4">erasfasfbar4asfer</a><br>
```

to this?

```
<a href="http://foo.bar1">asfdlksafbar1qsasadf</a><br>
<a href="http://foo.bar2">svasfbar2saldkfj</a><br>
<a href="http://foo.bar3">safdfrh<font style=BACKGROUND-COLOR:red>bar3</font>saljfd</a><br>
<a href="http://foo.bar4">erasfasfbar4asfer</a><br>
```

So only the `bar3` would be highlighted, only if it occurs between the:

```
">xxx</a>
```

I am using ksh/OpenBSD.

Comment: `sed 's|\(\">\w*\)\(bar3\)\(\w*</a>\)|\1<font style=BACKGROUND-COLOR:red>\2</font>\3|'`

Comment: hmm, it doesn't work on OpenBSD's ksh :\

Comment: Have you tried as : `sed -i 's|\(\">\w*\)\(bar3\)\(\w*</a>\)|\1<font style=BACKGROUND-COLOR:red>\2</font>\3|' <filename>` ?

Comment: html is not a context-free grammar, so you will never get a good solution using `sed`. Have you considered using a different language such as python?

Comment: @Costas I ask you again: _please stop giving answers in comments!_

Comment: Parsing HTML with REs [is not going to work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) for anything other than the [simplest of substitutions](http://esr.ibiblio.org/?p=1411). Really.

Answer (score 1):

The following should work on any system with Perl:

```
perl -pe 's/(>.*)(bar3)(.*<\/a>)/$1<font style=BACKGROUND-COLOR:red>$2<\/font>$3/'
```

At least it does the right thing on your example file; the regexp in `s/regexp/replacement/` asks to match `bar3` between `>` and `</a>`, as you asked, but if your real-world HTML input is more complex than this, it may prove too simplistic. Please provide more details on your requirements if so.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
awk -v pattern="bar3" 'match($0, pattern){
  beg = index( $0, ">")
  content = gensub(/<.*$/, "", "", gensub(/^[^>]+>/, "", "", $0))
  beg_str = index( content, pattern)
  if (match (content, pattern)) {
    print substr($0, 0, beg) substr(content, 0, beg_str - 1)  "<fontstyle=BACKGROUND-COLOR:red>" substr(content, beg_str, length(pattern)) "</font>" substr(content, beg_str + length(pattern)) "</a><br>"
    next
  }
}
{print}' file.html
```

Hope it works on ksh

Answer (score 0):

This solution requires the GNU version of awk...

```
awk '{ print gensub(/(>.*)(bar3)(.*<\/a>)/,"\\1<font style=BACKGROUND-COLOR:red>\\2</font>\\3","g") }' yourfile.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Any answer will depend on what you can actually know about your input.

If you know you want the second `bar3` surrounded by `<font>`, you could do:

```
perl -pe 's#(.*bar3.*)(bar3)#$1<font style=BACKGROUND-COLOR:red>$2</font>#' file
```

or

```
sed 's#\(.*bar3.*\)\(bar3\)#\1<font style=BACKGROUND-COLOR:red>\2</font>#' file
```

or, with GNU `sed`:

```
sed -r 's#(.*bar3.*)(bar3)#\1<font style=BACKGROUND-COLOR:red>\2</font>#' file
```

---

If you want to change all occurrences of `bar3` that fall between a `>` and a `<` (with no `<` in between), you could do:

```
perl -pe 's#(>[^<]*)(bar3)([^<]*<)#$1<font style=BACKGROUND-COLOR:red>$2</font>$3#' file
```

or

```
sed 's#\(>[^<]*\)\(bar3\)\([^<]*<\)#\1<font style=BACKGROUND-COLOR:red>\2</font>\3#' file
```

or, with GNU `sed`

```
sed -r 's#(>[^<]*)(bar3)([^<]*<)#\1<font style=BACKGROUND-COLOR:red>\2</font>\3#' file
```

---

If you want to replace any `bar3` that start on the 33rd position of a line, you can do:

```
perl -pe 's#(.{32})(bar3)#$1<font style=BACKGROUND-COLOR:red>$2</font>#' file
```

or

```
sed 's#\(.\{32\}\)\(bar3\)#\1<font style=BACKGROUND-COLOR:red>\2</font>#' file
```

or, with GNU `sed`

```
sed -r 's#(.{32})(bar3)#\1<font style=BACKGROUND-COLOR:red>\2</font>#' file
```

There are other options, of course, but they will always depend on exactly what you can be certain of about your input data.